# Unity 3D Finding Vertices Location and Re sizing Mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, unityscript, mesh

I want to find the vertices location in a mesh and then scale the vertices of a custom mesh on run-time.

To be precise, I have a 3d model of shirt and measurements of various body parts (like chest, belly, waist etc) as floating point numbers. Now I want to scale the mesh with these measurements.

I have got vertices of a mesh in unity, but when i re-size them in a for loop it obviously effects all the vertices. I need different scale on different locations, I don't know how to differentiate the vertices, like to locate which vertices are for chest and which are for belly etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bones for that. If you'll [rig the mesh to different bones in your 3d editor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preparingacharacterfromscratch.html), you'll have bone objects when you import the model to unity (just don't forget to enable importing the rig in the import settings). And when you move and scale the bone objects around, the mesh vertices will move and scale too, according to the bone weights. You won't even have to write any code to deal with vertices yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Sir. I am able to scale a dress in unity, say shirt after rigging it with humanoid like bones in blender.
Now is there any criteria to scale the bones for the measurements that i have stored? 
For example if i have to scale the shirt to 36 inches from chest, how much should i scale the chest bone from 1. how can i know that?

Comment: I don't know anything about dress sizes, unfortunately.